# mysqli insert statement problems

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

am getting the following error from my code:

Binding parameters failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? (Name, Address, Location, Phone, Email, Time, Website, Photo1, Rating, Date_Pu' at line 1

Can anyone help me out please? Here is my code:

```
include("mysqli.php");
$search_tbl = mysql_query("SELECT * from listing_title where listing_title_ID = '$main_id'");
$tbl_name = $search_tbl['tbl_name'];

                        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
                        global $tbl_name;
                        if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO ? (Name, Address, Location, Phone, Email, Time, Website, Photo1, Rating, Date_Published, categories_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) 
                        {
                                      $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssisi',$tbl_name,$title,$address,$location,$phone,$email,$time,$website,$name,$rating,$date,$sub_cat);
                $title = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $address = $_POST['address'];
                $location = $_POST['location'];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                $time = $_POST['time'];
                $rating = $_POST['rating'];
                $main = $_POST['main'];
                $website = $_POST['website'];
                $date = date('Y-m-d');
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                              echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;

                            }


                    }
                    else
                    {

                    echo 'a';

                    }
```

Comment: Here's your first problem `mysql_query` then `bind_param` - they don't mix. Use `mysqli_*` functions exclusively. Plus, you're declaring your POST variables "after" your query.

Comment: Do indent your code properly.

Comment: Plus, you cannot do `INSERT INTO ?` table names are not "bind-able".

Comment: I *strongly* suggest that you go through the manual regarding prepared statements http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php including looking through *properly-written* tutorials.

Comment: Here are a few tutorials to look at: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/ and http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452 and do not, I repeat **DO NOT** mix `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` they will **bite you** in the "*you know what*". Thank goodness for this comment box, otherwise I'd be bound to fix this code. ;-)

Comment: Thank for you reply and advice Fred, Can you tell me how can i pass the table name in the statement as variable please?

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to use a variable for your table, simply assign it first, i.e.: `$table="table_name";` then do `INSERT into $table`

Comment: Thanks fred, i figured out my error.. Actually i forgot to fetch teh data for teh table name, There should be $result_tabl = mysql_fetch_array($search_tbl);

Answer (score 0):

your script appears to be incomplete, but doing the best i could with what you had this is what you need. first of all, ditch whatever mysqli wrapper crap you are using. it is teaching you bad principles.

first file, your db info. call it config.php or whatever the hell you want. use require once instead of include. also, ditch the parenthesis around the requires these are not necessary at all, and use single quotes instead of double quotes. single quotes are treated as strings while double quotes php will search for variables inside, thus spending more resources from the cpu/cache.

**config.php**

```
$host = 'localhost';//your db host
$user = 'someuser'; //your db user
$pass = 'somepass'; //your db password
$name = 'somedb'; //the name of your db
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno(); 
    exit; 
}else{
    global $mysqli;//make your db connection available globally
}
```

Now for your script

**script.php**

```
require_once 'config.php';

//keep your post variables up here. you still need to santize and trim these
$title = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$main = $_POST['main'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

global $mysqli;//fetch your db connection


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tbl_name from listing_title where listing_title_ID = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$main_id);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($tbl_name);
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name." 
    (Name, Address, Location, Phone, Email, Time, Website, Photo1, Rating, Date_Published, categories_ID) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssisi',$title,$address,$location,$phone,$email,$time,$website,$name,$rating,$date,$sub_cat);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
        $stmt->close();
        //catch the error
    }
}else{
    $stmt->close();
    //throw an exception or handle the error here.
}
```

Please note, this still needs work. you need to sanitize and trim your variables. here's an example function. to include funcs, just add a require_once to the config.php file, and it will be included in any file you include config.php in.

example of this:

`require_once 'funcs.php';`

**example sanitize function:**

**funcs.php**

```
function security($value) {
   if(is_array($value)) {
      $value = array_map('security', $value);
   } else {
      if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
         $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      } else {
         $value = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      }
      $value = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $value);
   }
   return $value;
}
```

to call the function

`$title =  security(trim($_POST['name']));`

I leave the sanitizing to you. its a valuable exercise and you have an example that will sanitize anything, whether it be integers, arrays, objects, or strings.

you should only use trims on strings though. if you want to sanitize an entire array, just use the security function.

good luck.